# Получить value  всех выбраных радио инпутов

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго времени суток.

Есть  код:

```
<div class="optionCatergory sade">
    <label class='searchClick'><input type='radio' checked='checked' value='A'>A</label>
    <label class='searchClick' ><input type='radio' value='b'>B</label>
</div>
<div class="optionCatergory view">
    <label class='searchClick' ><input type='radio' checked='checked value='1'>1</label>
    <label class='searchClick' ><input type='radio' value='2'>2</label>
</div>
```

Как добавить в массив, скажем, `new Arr все type='radio' checked='checked`  при загрузке страницы?

Comment: Нужен массив значений или самих нод?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать для перебора выбранных элементов функцию [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/), получается вот такой код:

```
var array = new Array();
$(".optionCatergory input[type='radio']:checked").each(function () {
    array.push($(this).val());
});
```

[Пример с выводом результата в консоль](http://jsfiddle.net/MasterAlex/Lwpsmnrk/)

Comment: Абшибка небольшая, вот исправленный вариант: https://jsfiddle.net/Lwpsmnrk/1/

Comment: @TheDoctor, ошибка, судя по всему, оказалась в html, который закопипастил из вопроса :)

Comment: @MasterAlex, угу :)

Comment: честно говоря, решил по-другому, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понял, что вы хотите добавить в массив, но вот селектор для инпутов. Выполнение происходит на загрузке страницы. Судя по тегу, против jquery вы ничего не имеете)) Дальше уж делайте с ними что хотите

```
$(function ()
{
   var allInputs = $(".optionCatergory input[type='radio']:checked");
   //do something
});
```

Comment: я просил в массив, а для сокращения кода можно написать было и 
var allInputs = $(".optionCatergory input:radio:checked"); 
или просто 
var allInputs = $(".optionCatergory input:checked"); 
до этого я и сам додумался

Comment: Но мне нужно в массив.

Comment: @Sergalas так

    $(...).map(function(o){ return $(o).val() })

Comment: нет, ничего не получилось

Comment: @Sergalas вряд ли ты сильно старался

    var a = $.map($(".optionCatergory input:radio:checked"), function(o){ return $(o).val() });

Comment: код был один в один. Но не судьба :(